# Filtering with React does not work as expected

Tags: reactjs, filter, state, use-effect

I am trying to filter an array of cars whenever any of my 3 filters changes. The way I see fit -for the moment- with React is to: check all filters whenever any of them changes, in this order: handleOnChangeDateFilter (where I set all my cars to the initial state if this filter is not set), handleOnChangeFuelFilter, handleOnChangeSeats.  I displayed some `console.log`s but for some reason (I think it might be something related to rendering and **when** useEffect runs. It runs after every re-render **OR** after any of the values in the dependency array changes, right?) (PS: I know I could somehow check to compare the new values with the old values by somehow capturing the prevState, so that I do not run a specific filter again with no reason, but forgot how to capture prevState. Will do that later, as it should work fine without that now, too)

So, any idea why the below code does not work?

```js
import moment from "moment";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Spinner from "../components/Spinner";
import { Col, Row, DatePicker, Select } from "antd";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import DefaultLayout from "../components/DefaultLayout";
import { getAllCars } from "../redux/actions/carsActions";
import cron from "node-cron";

const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;

function Home() {
  
  const { cars } = useSelector((state) => state.carsReducer); // state aici e de fapt store-ul nostru!

  const [timeRange, setTimeRange] = useState([]);
  const [fuelTypes, setFuelTypes] = useState([]);
  const [seatNumbers, setSeatNumbers] = useState([]);

  const { loading } = useSelector((state) => state.alertsReducer);
  const [totalCars, setTotalcars] = useState([]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("merge!");
    dispatch(getAllCars());
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("cars bro", cars);
    setFuelTypes(
      [...new Set(cars.map((car) => car.fuelType.toLowerCase()))].sort()
    );

    setSeatNumbers(
      [...new Set(cars.map((car) => car.capacity))].sort((a, b) => a - b)
    );

    setTotalcars(cars);
  }, [cars]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("refilter is triggered!");
    refilter();
  }, [timeRange, fuelTypes, seatNumbers]);


  function handleOnChangeDateFilter() {


    console.log("intra in handleOnChangeDateFilter", timeRange);
    console.log("totalCars:", totalCars);
    if (timeRange.length === 0) {
      console.log(
        "No date range filter specified!  Will reinitialize and then proceed with other filters!"
      );
      setTotalcars(cars);
      return;
    }
    var selectedFrom = moment(timeRange[0], "MMM DD yyyy HH:mm");
    var selectedTo = moment(timeRange[1], "MMM DD yyyy HH:mm");
    console.log("selectedFrom", selectedFrom, "selectedTo", selectedTo);

    var temp = [];

    for (var car of cars) {
      if (car.bookedTimeSlots.length === 0) {
        temp.push(car);
      } else {
        var toAdd = true;
        for (var booking of car.bookedTimeSlots) {
          if (
            selectedFrom.isBetween(booking.from, booking.to) ||
            selectedTo.isBetween(booking.from, booking.to) ||
            moment(booking.from).isBetween(selectedFrom, selectedTo) ||
            moment(booking.to).isBetween(selectedFrom, selectedTo)
          ) {
            console.log(
              `${car.name} is booked from ${booking.from} to ${booking.to}! Will NOT be added!`
            );
            toAdd = false;
            break; // we should not add this car to the displayed cars if we found a minimum of one booking that
            // intersects non-available time range
          }
        }
        if (toAdd) temp.push(car);
      }
    }

    setTotalcars(temp);
  }

  function handleOnChangeFuelFilter() {
    console.log(`intra in handleOnChangeFuelFilter:`, totalCars);
    if (fuelTypes === []) {
      console.log("no fuel filter specified! Will leave function!");
      return;
    }
    var temp = [];
    for (var car of totalCars) {
      if (fuelTypes.includes(car.fuelType.toLowerCase())) {
        // console.log(`${car.name} is of type ${car.fuelType}! Will be added!`);
        temp.push(car);
      }
    }
    setTotalcars(temp);
  }

  function handleOnChangeSeatsFilter() {
    console.log(`intra in handleOnChangeSeatsFilter:`, totalCars);
    if (seatNumbers === []) {
      console.log("No seat filter specified! Will leave function!");
      return;
    }
    var temp = [];
    for (var car of totalCars) {
      if (seatNumbers.includes(car.capacity)) {
        // console.log(`${car.name} has ${car.capacity}! Will be added!`);
        temp.push(car);
      }
    }
    setTotalcars(temp);
  }

  function onRangePickerFilterChange(values) {
    console.log("============STARTED============");
    console.log("onRangePickerFilterChange ->", values);
    setTimeRange(values);
  }

  function onSeatsFilterChange(values) {
    console.log("============STARTED============");
    console.log("onSeatsFilterChange ->", values);
    setSeatNumbers(values);
  }

  function onFuelFilterChange(values) {
    console.log("============STARTED============");
    console.log("onFuelFilterChange ->", values);
    setFuelTypes(values);
  }

  function refilter() {
    // console.log('values refilter:', values);
    // console.log('============STARTED============');
    handleOnChangeDateFilter();
    console.log("AFTER DATE FILTER:", totalCars);
    handleOnChangeFuelFilter();
    console.log("AFTER FUEL FILTER:", totalCars);
    handleOnChangeSeatsFilter();
    console.log("AFTER SEATS FILTER(final):", totalCars);
    console.log("============FINISHED============");
  }

  return (
    <DefaultLayout>
      <Row className="mt-3" justify="center">
        <Col lg={20} sm={24} className="d-flex justify-content-left">
          <RangePicker
            // ref={refRangePicker}
            showTime={{ format: "HH:mm" }}
            format="MMM DD yyyy HH:mm"
            // onChange={handleOnChangeDateFilter}
            // onChange={refilter}
            onChange={onRangePickerFilterChange}
          />
          <Select
            // onChange={handleFuelFilterChange}
            // onChange={refilter}
            onChange={onFuelFilterChange}
            allowClear
            mode="multiple"
            placeholder="Fuel type"
            style={{ width: "10%" }}
          >
            {fuelTypes.map((fuelType, index) => {
              return (
                <Select.Option key={index} value={fuelType}>
                  {fuelType}
                </Select.Option>
              );
            })}
          </Select>
          <Select
            // onChange={refilter}
            onChange={onSeatsFilterChange}
            allowClear
            mode="multiple"
            placeholder="Seats"
            style={{ width: "10%" }}
          >
            {seatNumbers.map((seatNumber, index) => {
              return (
                <Select.Option key={index} value={seatNumber}>
                  {seatNumber}
                </Select.Option>
              );
            })}
          </Select>
        </Col>
      </Row>

      {loading === true && <Spinner />}

      <Row justify="center" gutter={16}>
        {totalCars.map((car) => {
          return (
            <Col lg={5} sm={24} xs={24}>
              <div className="car p-1 bs1">
                <img src={car.image} className="carimg" />

                <div className="car-content d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                  <div className="text-left pl-2">
                    <p>{car.name}</p>
                    <p>
                      <sup>{car.rentPerHour} eur</sup>/<sub>Hour</sub>
                    </p>
                  </div>

                  <div className="text-left pl-2">
                    <p>Seats: {car.capacity}</p>
                  </div>

                  <div className="text-left pl-2">
                    <p>Fuel: {car.fuelType}</p>
                  </div>

                  <div>
                    <button className="btn1 mr-2">
                      <Link to={`/booking/${car._id}`}>Book Now</Link>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Col>
          );
        })}
      </Row>
    </DefaultLayout>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the filtering logic, not the useEffects or anything else strictly related to React. Here is the full working code (could be improved, but this is a working solution):

```js
import moment from "moment";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Spinner from "../components/Spinner";
import { Col, Row, DatePicker, Select } from "antd";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import DefaultLayout from "../components/DefaultLayout";
import { getAllCars } from "../redux/actions/carsActions";

const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;

function Home() {
  const { cars } = useSelector((store) => {
    console.log("in callback:", store.carsReducer);
    return store.carsReducer;
  });

  const [timeRange, setTimeRange] = useState([]);
  const [fuelTypes, setFuelTypes] = useState([]); // all present fuel types in my DB (initialized in first useEffect)
  const [seatNumbers, setSeatNumbers] = useState([]); // all present seat capacity numbers in my DB (initialized in first useEffect)

  const [selectedTimeRange, setSelectedTimeRange] = useState([]);
  const [selectedFuelTypes, setSelectedFuelTypes] = useState([]); // selected fuel types (selected by the user from the antd Select.Option component)
  const [selectedSeatNumbers, setSelectedSeatNumbers] = useState([]); // selected seat numbers (selected by the user from the antd Select.Option component)

  const { loading } = useSelector((store) => store.alertsReducer);
  const [totalCars, setTotalCars] = useState([]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllCars());
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFuelTypes(
      [...new Set(cars.map((car) => car.fuelType.toLowerCase()))].sort()
    ); // all possible fuel types
    setSeatNumbers(
      [...new Set(cars.map((car) => car.capacity))].sort((a, b) => a - b)
    ); // all possible seat numbers
    setTotalCars(cars); // all cars
  }, [cars]);

  useEffect(() => {
    refilter();
  }, [selectedTimeRange, selectedFuelTypes, selectedSeatNumbers]);

  function refilter() {
    // no need for 3 separate functions (that would mean setting the state of the totalCars variable 3 times
    // using the `setTotalCars` function - which -if I am not mistaken- might trigger unexpected behavior
    // with the re-rendering of the component)
    // temporary array; eventually, totalCars will be assigned `temp` value using the `setTotalCars` method!
    var temp = [];

    // logica timeRange
    if (selectedTimeRange.length === 0) {
      console.log("user selected no time range");
      temp = [...cars];
    } else {
      console.log('user selected timeRange: ', selectedTimeRange);
      var selectedFrom = moment(selectedTimeRange[0], "MMM DD yyyy HH");
      var selectedTo = moment(selectedTimeRange[1], "MMM DD yyyy HH");

      for (var car of cars) {
        if (car.bookedTimeSlots.length == 0) {
          temp.push(car);
        } else {
          var toBeAdded = true;
          for (var booking of car.bookedTimeSlots) {
            if (selectedFrom.isBetween(booking.from, booking.to) ||
                selectedTo.isBetween(booking.from, booking.to) ||
                moment(booking.from).isBetween(selectedFrom, selectedTo) ||
                moment(booking.to).isBetween(selectedFrom, selectedTo)) {
                  toBeAdded = false; // if time range of booking overlaps with selected time range, don't add car to temp!
                  break;
            }
          }
          if (toBeAdded) {
            temp.push(car);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // fuelTypes logic
    if (selectedFuelTypes.length !== 0){
      console.log('User selected fuel types: ', selectedFuelTypes);
      temp = temp.filter((car) => selectedFuelTypes.includes(car.fuelType));
      console.log(`filtered by fuelTypes: ${temp}`);
    }

    // seatsNumber logic
    if (selectedSeatNumbers.length !== 0){
      console.log('User selected seat numbers: ', selectedSeatNumbers);
      temp = temp.filter((car) => selectedSeatNumbers.includes(car.capacity));
      console.log(`filtered by seatsNumber: ${temp.length}`);
    }

    // finally, assign filtered values to totalCars!
    console.log("temp:", temp);
    setTotalCars(temp);
  }

  return (
    <DefaultLayout>
      <Row className="mt-3" justify="center">
        <Col lg={20} sm={24} className="d-flex justify-content-left">
          <RangePicker
            showTime={{ format: "HH:mm" }}
            format="MMM DD yyyy HH:mm"
            onChange={(values) => {
              setSelectedTimeRange(values);
            }}
          />
          <Select
            allowClear
            mode="multiple"
            placeholder="Fuel"
            style={{ width: "10%" }}
            onChange={(values) => {
              setSelectedFuelTypes(values);
            }}
          >
            {fuelTypes.map((fuelType, index) => {
              return (
                <Select.Option key={index} value={fuelType}>
                  {fuelType}
                </Select.Option>
              );
            })}
          </Select>
          <Select
            onChange={(values) => {
              setSelectedSeatNumbers(values);
            }}
            allowClear
            mode="multiple"
            placeholder="Seats"
            style={{ width: "10%" }}
          >
            {seatNumbers.map((seatNumber, index) => {
              return (
                <Select.Option key={index} value={seatNumber}>
                  {seatNumber}
                </Select.Option>
              );
            })}
          </Select>
        </Col>
      </Row>

      {loading === true && <Spinner />}

      <Row justify="center" gutter={16}>
        {totalCars.map((car) => {
          return (
            <Col lg={5} sm={24} xs={24}>
              <div className="car p-1 bs1">
                <img src={car.image} className="carimg" />

                <div className="car-content d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                  <div className="text-left pl-2">
                    <p>{car.name}</p>
                    <p>
                      <sup>{car.rentPerHour} eur</sup>/<sub>Hour</sub>
                    </p>
                  </div>

                  <div className="text-left pl-2">
                    <p>Seats: {car.capacity}</p>
                  </div>

                  <div className="text-left pl-2">
                    <p>Fuel: {car.fuelType}</p>
                  </div>

                  <div>
                    <button className="btn1 mr-2">
                      <Link to={`/booking/${car._id}`}>Book Now</Link>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Col>
          );
        })}
      </Row>
    </DefaultLayout>
  );
}

export default Home;
```